# Why does the HTTP protocol based on TCP?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, udp, protocols

Why have people done the HTTP protocol based on TCP, and not based on UDP?

Comment: please google before asking a new question

Comment: I don't think anyone who knows how TCP and UDP work would ask this question...

Comment: Ok... I read in Google, it says that TCP is used for packet delivery guarantees. That's it?

Comment: Imagine a world where Wikipedia articles are modified by your microwave oven when you use wifi in the kitchen.  That's what you're proposing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP guarantees reliable transmission of data where UDP doesn't. This means if they were to implement HTTP over UDP, they would have to add the reliable transmission mechanism (e.g. error checking) in the application layer, which is simply unnecessary. People prefer reliability over performance when it comes to web browsing.